# C program giving incorrect output for simple math!

Tags: c

(all are declared as ints, none are initialized to anything beforehand. I have included math.h and am compiling with -lm)

```
cachesize = atoi(argv[1]);
blocksize = atoi(argv[3]);
setnumber = (cachesize/blocksize);
printf("setnumber: %d\n", setnumber);
setbits = (log(setnumber))/(log(2));
printf("sbits: %d\n", setbits);
```

when given cachesize as 1024 and blocksize as 16 the output is as follows:

```
setnumber: 64
sbits: 5
```

but log(64)/log(2) = 6 !

It works correctly when given cachesize 512 and blocksize 32. I can't seem to win.

I'm really hoping that it's a stupid mistake on my part, and I'd be grateful if anyone could point out what it is! Thank you!

PS: I posted this in Yahoo Answers first but that was probably silly. Won't be doing that again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[log](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/log.html) returns a double.  You should round instead of truncate.  However, you can use [log2](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/log2.html) here.

Comment: In addition, there is a `log2()` function to directly get base 2 logarithms, instead of doing that division yourself.

Comment: You posted that a second before I added that, Carl. :)

Comment: I read that log2 requires "-std=c99" and I'm lazy with my makefiles. 

If I have another question in the same program but unrelated to this problem should I post it here or make a whole new question?

Comment: @DuffDuff: Questions on unrelated issues should be posted separately. That said, the answer is probably `CFLAGS += -std=c99`

Comment: Hahaha, that is NOT what I was going to ask, but thank you. =D

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that neither `log(2)` or `log(setnumber)` are exactly representable as floating-point numbers, and their rounding errors are conspiring to cause their quotient to round down to something just smaller than `6`, which then truncates to `5` when you convert to integer.

Using `log2( )` will solve this problem on some platforms that have a good-quality math library, but the C standard does not actually guarantee anything about the accuracy of `log( )` or `log2( )` (indeed, some platforms just implement `log2( )` as `log( )/log(2)`, so it may give you the same problem you're having now).

You want to use the `ilogb( )` function, which returns the exponent of its argument as a signed integer value.

```
setbits = ilogb(setnumber);
```

This has the added benefit of being quite a bit faster on some platforms.

(Admittedly, this use `ilogb` is not portable to systems that use non-radix-2 floating-point, but that's a much smaller concern then platforms that just have shoddy math libraries)